# Does there exist a linear automorphism $\alpha\colon\mathbb{Q}[x]\to\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $\alpha\circ\varphi=\psi\circ\alpha$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, solution-verification

I'm currently working on linear algebra with polynomials, and there is an exercise I am not sure how to solve, so below you will find what I've done, please tell me if I'm on the right path or not.

We consider $\varphi,\psi$ to be linear endomorphisms of the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ of the polynomials, given by $\varphi(P(x)) =P′(x), \psi(P(x)) = P(x + 1) − P(x)$. The question if the following: does there exist a linear automorphism $\alpha\colon \mathbb{Q}[x] \to \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $\alpha\circ\varphi=\psi\circ\alpha$?

If I understand well, we are looking for $\alpha$ such that $\alpha(\varphi(P(x))) = \psi(\alpha(P(x)))$, i.e $\alpha(P'(x)) = \alpha(P(x) + 1) - \alpha(P(x))$

Now there is the part I have a doubt about: since $P(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, it is of the form $P(x) = ax + b$, for $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ right ? i.e $P'(x) = a$, and if that's right then we want to know if there exists $\alpha$ such that

$$\alpha(a) = \alpha(ax + b + 1) - \alpha(ax + b) $$

Moreover we are looking for $\alpha$ linear, therefore:

$$\alpha(a - ax - b - 1 + ax + b)) = 0 \iff \alpha(a - 1) = 0$$

And I believe this $\alpha$ can be found in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, taking simply the constant map sending each polynomial to zero: $\alpha(P(x)) \mapsto 0$.

However I feel like I missed a detail, could anyone tell me what is right and/or wrong in this proof?

**EDIT:**

Since I could not work out with the basis given in the comments yet, I tried to do something else:

$\alpha \circ \varphi = \psi \circ \alpha \iff \alpha(\varphi(P(x))) = \psi(\alpha(P(x))) \iff \alpha(P'(x)) = \alpha(P(x) + 1) - \alpha(P(x)) \iff$ (by linearity of $\alpha)$ $\alpha(P'(x) - 1) = 0$

But again I'm not sure where this leads, and I woudl really like to understand the method introduced in the comments of this post rather, so any help is welcome!

Comment: The paragraph starting with "Now there is the part" is very hard to follow.  $P(x)\in \mathbb{Q}$ doesn't make sense, it doesn't follow that $P(x)$ is a linear polynomial, and no linear polynomial satisfies $P'(x) = x$.  It's unclear what you're trying to say here.  Also, I don't understand how $\alpha$ being linear implies that its value on $x-1$ is zero.  But in whatever case, the conclusion is certainly wrong, since the zero map has no inverse and so it isn't an automorphism.

Comment: The line "$P(x)\in\mathbb{Q}$ , it is of the form $P(x)=ax+b$" isn't right. Presumably it starts with a typo, you mean "$P(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$"; but there's no reason to assume $P$ is of degree $1$.Also $\alpha=0$ is not an automorphism.

Comment: It was indeed a typo at first, which I corrected, but I saw $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ as $\mathbb{Q}_1[x]$ so I took a polynomial of degree 1. However I now see this is wrong, so can I try again with a polynomial of the form P(x) = a + bx + cx^2 + ...

Comment: My hint would be: look for two bases of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that (i) for the first basis $\phi$ moves them all down one, ie take $e_r=x^r/r!$ and (ii) for the second basis $\psi$ moves them all down one, perhaps $f_r= x(x+1)(x+2)\dots (x+r-1)/r!$ - think "Pascal triangle identity" to see this works .

Comment: Sorry @ancientmathematician but I don't understand what you mean by "moves them all down one", could you explain ?

Comment: $e_0\mapsto 0$, $e_{n+1}\mapsto e_n$ and same for $f_r$.

Comment: Okey @ancientmathematician, so I've been trying for some time to use those basis to prove or disprove the existence of the automorphism $\alpha$, however I didn't achieve to use Pascal triangle identity as you suggested,do you think you could develop a bit more your idea? Sorry I'm currently following an advanced class for which I didn't attend the elementary class, so I can get a bit confused depending on the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following bases of $\mathbb{Q}[X]$:

$$
e_k:=\frac{x^k}{k!} \text{ for } k=0,1,\dots
$$
and
$$
f_0:=1, f_k:={x \choose k} \text{ for } k=1,\dots
$$
where $x\choose k$ denotes the polynomial $\frac{x(x+1)\dots(x+k-1)}{k!}$.

Now we have at once that
$$
\phi e_0=0 \text{ and } \phi e_{k+1}=e_k.
$$
But we also have
$$
\psi f_0= 1-1=0,  \text{ and } \psi f_{k+1}= {x+1\choose k+1}-{x\choose k+1}={x\choose k}=f_k.
$$

That is $\phi$ and $\psi$ are similar, and for $\alpha$ we can take the automorphism carrying each $e_i$ to $f_i$.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot I understand it all now!